# Can I repurpose a room?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I made a storage room, but now I can't have my kid live in the house I built. Is there anyway I could change the storage room into a child's room?

Comment: Sophia, check out the question I linked in the previous comment. If it doesn't answer your question, let us know.

Comment: Also important is that the Storage Room is a North Wing option, while the Family Bedroom is a West Wing option.  Other North Wing options are Alchemy Tower or Trophy Room.  West wing options are Enchanting Tower or Greenhouse.

Answer (score 0):

Based on posts [in this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/63989620), it does not look like you can change rooms once they are built.

> Unfortunately you can't change anything once it's built.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are able to have 2 child beds setup without any of the house extensions, so you really never need to do this for adopting children.